# html/css alignment issue because of an empty <span>. What is moving my content down?

Tags: css, web, html

I have an alignment problem in html/css. I simplified my problem to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        span { display: inline-block; height: 50px; }
        span.text { background-color: Yellow;}
        span.left, span.right { background-color: Red;  width: 20px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="left">x</span>
    <span class="text">Text comes here</span>
    <span class="right">x</span>
</body>
</html>
```

The output in the browser is as expected:

[image]

However, span.left and span.right should not contain any content. They are there for layout purposes only. But when I remove the content ("x") of both spans like this:

```
<span class="left"></span>
<span class="text">Text comes here</span>
<span class="right"></span>
```

The output changes to this:

[image]

Why is it doing this? What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vertical align is problematic, since it is set to the default *baseline*. Just change it to top:

```
span { display: inline-block; height: 50px;vertical-align:top; }
```

Comment: Yes, this is working, thank you! So the baseline of a an empty span is considered the bottom edge of the span itself? But if it contains text, it's the baseline of the text in the span? Weird...