# CSS with span alignment in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have the following case:
Edited: removed link

In IE7 gives me different view - the three elements are not top aligned.
In other browsers code looks ok.

Please suggest what to do with alignment of the three elements?

HTML Code:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title> Text </title>
  <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class="button-like">
    <a href="">
        <span class="left-button"></span>
        <span class="right-button"></span>
        Text text text
    </a>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
.button-like{
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
/* Elipsis */
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%; /*IE 6*/
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;} 

.button-like a{
    max-width: 410px;
margin-left: 35px;
margin-right: 35px;
padding: 0 40px;
position: relative;
height: 38px;
color: #52455f;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 40px;
display: inline-block;
background: url("/imgs/button-tile.png") 0 0 repeat-x transparent;
}

.left-button{
left: -35px;
position: absolute;
width: 35px;
height: 38px;
background: url("/imgs/button-left.png") 0 0 no-repeat transparent;
}

.right-button{
left: auto;
right: -35px;
position: absolute;
width: 35px;
height: 38px;
background: url("/imgs/button-right.png") 0 0 no-repeat transparent;
}
```

Comment: I can't display the link you provided. Takes too much time. edit: maybe provide a jsfiddle and paste minimal code here?

Comment: You should post a [Short, Self-Contained Example](http://sscce.org/) code in your question, so other people can get help after you fix your site.  Also, you can post that same code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see a working example of the problem.

Comment: Edited, removed link, will try also in JSFiddle - but wil it work in IE7?

Comment: Do you really not have a doctype? If so, I would expect all versions of IE including IE7/8/9 to all render the page in the same way: broken (quirks mode).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JVZ6K/1/ in IE7 doesnt show properly aligned three elements

Comment: I omitted in the code pasting - but I do have doctype <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

Comment: Searched again - seems to find the answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125916/html-css-alignment-issue-because-of-an-empty-span-what-is-moving-my-content-d                                                           How to close the question?

Comment: [That doctype doesn't seem to be valid.](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsbin.com%2Fuqowem&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) Try changing to `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Does anything change?

Comment: The answer you found doesn't seem to work in IE7 for me. I've worked out the actual problem, so I'll post an answer...

Comment: @thirtydot - you are right - my html was different, your answer is working - accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `top: 0` to `.left-button` and `.right-button` because they have `position: absolute` and IE7 is buggy.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/JVZ6K/5/